# в цикле брать из списка ключ и значение ключа Python

Tags: python

Нужно каждый раз в цикле брать следующее название каши и цену из списка

```
a = {"манная каша":"30","гречневая каша":"20"}

while True:
    print()#тут нужно название каши
    print("Cтоимость:")  # тут нужна цена каши
```

Должен получится вот такой вывод:

```
манная каша
Стоимость:30
гречневая каша
Стоимость:20
```

Comment: `for k, v in a.items():`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взял ваш код + комментарий **Станислава**.

Вот какой получился результат

```
a = { "манная каша": "30", "гречневая каша": "20" }
for k, v in a.items():
  print( k ) #тут нужно название каши    
  print( "Cтоимость: " + v )  # тут нужна цена каши
    
'''
Bytovskiy
'''
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @Bytovskiy, если я правильно ответил на ваш вопрос, то пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой

Comment: @Bytovskiy, спасибо ))